# Combinations Array Java

Tags: java, arrays, combinations

Given a array for any dimension (for instance [1 2 3]), a function that gives all combinations like

1 |

1 2 |

1 2 3 |

1 3 |

2 |

2 1 3 |

2 3 |
...

Comment: Do you want *combinations* or *permutations*?  You said combinations, but you listed separately 123 and 213, which makes me think you might want permutations.

Comment: Permutations don't work either because "1" surely isn't a permutation of "123".

Comment: Why not 132 ? That seems to be a valid combination too.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm guessing this is homework, I'll try to refrain from giving a complete answer.

Suppose you already had all combinations (or permutations if that is what you are looking for) of an array of size n-1.  If you had that, you could use those combinations/permutations as a basis for forming the new combinations/permutations by adding the nth element to them in the appropriate way.  That is the basis for what computer scientists call [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) (and mathematicians like to call a very similar idea [induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction)).

So you could write a method that would handle the the n case, assuming the n-1 case had been handled, and you can put a check to handle the base case as well.